# Improper integral problem. $\int_9^\infty dx / [(x-8) (x-7)]$

Tags: calculus, integration

I worked the problem out and ended up with $\ln(x-8) - \ln (x-7)$. So according to the natural log rule, I can make the problem $\ln (x-8)/(x-7)$. And then when I plug 9 in, I end up with 1/2 as the answer. But the real answer is 2. Did I do the rule wrong? Is it $\ln (x-7)/(x-8)$?

Also, if someone could please explain how to tell when an integral is converging/diverging, that would be really helpful.

Comment: Are you asking for $\int^\infty_9\dfrac{dx}{(x-8)(x-7)}$ or $\int^\infty_9(x-7)\dfrac{dx}{(x-8)}$?

Comment: I'm asking for the first one, sorry!

Comment: Using Wolfram Alpha (http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=1%2F%28%28x-8%29%28x-7%29%29&random=false) gives
$$\lim_{b\to\infty}2\tanh^{-1}(15-2x)|^b_9$$

Comment: Your antiderivative is correct. The correct answer is $\log 2$ and you obtained $\log 1/2 = - \log 2$. So it's just a sign error. Did you subtract correctly?

Answer (score 4):

You did everything right. The indefinite integral is $$\ln{\frac{x-8}{x-7}}$$ At the two endpoints, you get $$\ln(1)-\ln({1\over 2})=\ln(2)$$

Comment: Can you please explain this step to me? @user137500

Comment: As x goes to infinity, the quotient inside the log tends to 1. When x is 9, the quotient is 1/2. So you take the log at 1 minus the log at 1/2. Then, log(1/2)=-log(2) by a property of logs, so there is a double negative, and ln(1)=0, so the answer is +ln(2).

Comment: thank you! Can you answer one more question please? Suppose the integral didn't involve logs. It was just whole numbers, how would it work then?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If it was 1 and 1/2, it would just be 1-1/2=1/2... I suppose that's not what you meant though. Could you clarify?